# Records not getting in ascending order

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML page with PHP code which inserts data to a MySQL database. The data gets saved to the DB without any errors but in an incorrect order.

This is the structure:
[image: screenshot of structure]

This is the database:
[image: screenshot of database]

This is the output:
[image: screenshot of output]

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT num,question,choice1,choice2,choice3,choice4, answer FROM data order by num';

mysql_select_db('test');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td> '.$row['num'].'.'.$row['question'].' <br/ >A.'.$row['choice1'].'<br />B.'.$row['choice2'].'<br />C.'.$row['choice3'].'<br />D.'.$row['choice4'].'<br />Answer.'.$row['answer'].'</td>';
    echo "<td text-align='center'><form action='proto2.php' method='post'>
          <input type='hidden' name='update' value=".$row['num']." />
          <input type='submit' value='Change' />
          </td></form> ";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

The fetching is inconsistent, it always start at number 11. I just don't know why number 11 and 2 switch places, any help? Also my database is strange because after 1 2 3 number 20 appear then 4 5 6.

And I even try this code but still I got the same result even I check by number or rows

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY  num ASC';

mysql_select_db('test');
$retval = mysql_query($sql);
$cntr = mysql_num_rows($retval);

mysql_close();
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
for($i = 1;$i<=$cntr+1;$i++)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT num,question,choice1,choice2,choice3,choice4,answer FROM data WHERE num='".$i."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td> '.$row['num'].'.'.$row['question'].' <br/ >A.'.$row['choice1'].'<br />B.'.$row['choice2'].'<br />C.'.$row['choice3'].'<br />D.'.$row['choice4'].'<br />Answer.'.$row['answer'].'</td>';
        echo "<td text-align='center'><form action='proto2.php' method='post'>
              <input type='hidden' name='update' value=".$row['num']." />
              <input type='submit' value='Change' />
              </td></form> ";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run your SQL query in phpmyadmin? What was the order of the result?

Comment: it is order by 1 2 3 20 19 4 5 6 i dont know how that happen

Comment: Print screen the table and post it as an edit to your question - it might help to give you an answer

Comment: the whole table or my database?

Answer (score 2):

Your result set is ordering by `num` alphabetically, rather than numerically. This is most likely because your `num` column is set as a VARCHAR instead of an INTEGER in MySQL. Change this in your database (with a tool like phpMyAdmin), and your results should order correctly.

Comment: my datatype for num is set for integer and i still got that same problem and it is auto increment because its the primary key... but when i took a look in my database it appears that it is not in numerical order

Comment: Could you provide us with an export or screenshot of the database structure, in the original answer?

Comment: I've just recreated your database on my local environment, and running the following query is working fine for me: `SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY num`

Comment: If that query doesn't produce the 1-11 ordered results, then there are a few things you should update in your database: 1) integers should only have a maximum size of 11 (you have 100), 2) varchar should only have a max size of 255 (you have 2000), and 3) you should set your `num` field as a primary key (the icon with the key on it)

Comment: its realy weird sir my sql is right but we dont have the same output i deleted my table once and create the same fields and data type and i got the same answer but my other queries are functioning right

Comment: Additionally, the default ordering for MySQL is no guarantee. You should try selecting the "num" column header when Browsing the table in phpmyadmin to make it order ASC, then review the SQL query it generates.

Comment: my table has a next page control and my limit per row is 10 you think that the jquery affect the sql?

Comment: I cannot see any jquery in your original question, and I don't suspect jquery to be the issue, but if you are doing jquery based pagination on the result set then your jquery could be reading the column number as a string rather than an integer. Do you have some jquery code you could post. It would also be good to be able to see a live version of this code if you could put it on a server somewhere?

Comment: i can give you the link where i downloaded the table and my codes for the fetching in the table

Comment: Yes, if you can provide the database dump I can import the db on my end and try everything with the code you have provided.

Comment: i dont know where i can post my sql but here is the link of the site http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/345/Advanced-JavaScript-table-Sorter

Comment: Yes, this is most likely where your issue lies. Have you tried loading the page without javascript enabled (in Chrome: View > Developer > Dev Tools > Settings(icon) > Disable JS), or viewing the HTML source of the page (View > Developer > View Source - not Inspect Element) to confirm the order of the records in HTML (before JS reorders them)? Additionally, can you add to your question all the JS you use on the page as this is likely less to do with MySQL and more to do with that plugin.